# Making object from array with similar keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array like this:

```
var array = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
```

I would like to make a new object from this array, and they should have the same keys. Desired outcome should be like this:

```
var objectFromArray = [
{ responsibilityName: "test1" },
{ responsibilityName: "test2" },
{ responsibilityName: "test3" },
{ responsibilityName: "test4"}
]
```

How is this possible in js?

Comment: `var data = array.map(el => ({responsibilityName: el}))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusted to your comment: you can use `reduce` and `map` to flatten the arrays within the array of objects.

[**Edit** based on your comment]

```js
const arr = [
  { responsabilityName: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'],
    somethingElse: [1, 2, 3, 4] } ];

const arrMapped = arr
  .reduce( (mappedArr, obj) => 
      Object.keys(obj)
        .map( key => obj[key].map( prop => ({ [key]: prop }) ) )
        .reduce( (p, n) => p.concat(n), [] ), 
   [] );

console.log(arrMapped);
```

Comment: or simply `data = array.map(el => ({responsibilityName: el}))` :)

Comment: The thing is that I am getting structure like this http://prntscr.com/h484nb. When I would like to have a structure like this http://prntscr.com/h484y2 (no ids, just responsibilityName)

Comment: @nikasv Adjusted the answer based on the structure you posted

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the array and return a new object using `map` or `forEach` etc.

```js
var array = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
var arr = array.map(value => {
    return {responsibilityName: value};
    
})
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array, create objects in the other one. As simple as that.

```
var array = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
var objectFromArray = []
array.forEach((v)=>{objectFromArray.push({"responsibilityname":v})})
```

Answer (score 0):

use **`array.map`** and assign the value to the object

**DEMO**

```js
var array = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'];

var result = array.map(function(el) {
    var obj = {};
    obj['responsibilityname'] = el;
   
  return obj;
})

console.log(array);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: or simply: `data = array.map(el => ({responsibilityName: el}))` :)

Comment: The thing is that I am getting structure like this http://prntscr.com/h484nb. When I would like to have a structure like this http://prntscr.com/h484y2 (no ids, just responsibilityName)